# Anklet of Translocation past a door or wall

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Anklet of Translocation says "The new space must be within line of sight and line of effect." Lets say a door or wall has a window, would the "line of effect" wording stop me from going to the other side of the wall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the quote you want:

> An otherwise solid barrier with a hole of at least 1 square foot through it does not block a spell’s line of effect.

If the window is an actual hole (ie, there is no glass in it) and it is at least a square foot in size, then you have line of effect and can translocate.

Comment: @Ozuma Line of effect and line of sight are two related concepts that are important to determining what you can and can’t target, what cover or concealment something you target has, and so on. Glass blocks line of effect, but not line of sight. Dense fog blocks line of sight, but not line of effect. Solid objects block both, clear air blocks neither. Etc. Line of effect is usually mandatory, but many effects can be used without line of sight, often by taking penalties. And some effects—particularly long-distance teleportation—don’t even need line of effect.

Comment: @KRyan Even *dimension door* — required for the creation of an *anklet of translocation* — permits teleportation without needing line of sight or effect.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, technically, *dimension door* **does** need line of effect, but only on the Astral Plane, not the material plane. Should access to the Astral Plane be somehow blocked in a certain region, for example, *dimension door* will fail to work in said region. Though your players may hate you or possibly throw things at you, it is something that secretive and/or paranoid villains would take into account when building their evil lair. (referencing the Manual of the Planes)